# Normalize numbers in array by custom number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some dataset:

```
const dataset = [14, 50, 202, 208, 55];
```

And I have to create a new array using `dataset` like this:

```
const normalizedDataset = normalize(dataset, 5); // [15, 50, 200, 210, 55]
```

Had tried to write some function to do it, but unfortunately I have no brain to solve this problem. Tried like this:

```
const normalize = (arr, n) => {  
  return arr.map(x => {
    const y = (x % n) > n / 2 ? x + (n - (x % n)) : (x % n);
    return y ? y : x;
  });
}
normalize(dataset, 5);
```

Maybe someone know some libs to do it or how to update my own function?

Comment: It is not quite obvious what are you exactly trying to achieve. How are you trying to normaline array?

Comment: What do you mean by "And I have to create a new array using dataset". Please explain what exactly do you wan to do?

Comment: @KamranEyyubov i have to do `normalize(dataset, 5)` and get `[15, 50, 200, 210, 55]`

Comment: When you say normalize, do you rounding to the nearest multiple? As in if the parameter is 5, each number in the data set is rounded to the nearest multiple of 5?

Comment: @Minidodds exactly! I am so sorry I did't know how that name for this operations `rounded to the nearest multiple of`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` and remainder `%` operator and based on `n` and what remains calculate new numbers.

```js
const dataset = [14, 50, 202, 208, 55];

function normalize(data, n) {
  return data.map(function(e) {
    var m = e % n;
    if (m == 0) return e;
    else {
      if (m > n / 2) return e + (n - m)
      else return e - m
    }
  })
}

console.log(normalize(dataset, 5))
```

Or shorter version with ternary operator could look like this.

```js
const dataset = [14, 50, 202, 208, 55];

const normalize = (data, n) => {
  return data.map(function(e) {
    var m = e % n;
    return (m != 0) ? (m > (n / 2) ? e + (n - m) : e - m) : e
  })
}

console.log(normalize(dataset, 5))
```

Comment: Thank you Nenad! You helped me so much!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this one is the shortest solution.

```js
const dataset = [14, 50, 202, 208, 55];

function normalize(arr, n){
 return arr.map(function(e){
  return Math.round(e/n)*n;
 })
}

console.log(normalize(dataset, 5));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kamran!